# Get Information about available parameters of report via XBP

Tags: abap

I would like to get information about a report. I want to know which values are available if I call the report like this:

```
SUBMIT (IV_REPORT_NAME)
   WITH SELECTION-TABLE selection_table
  AND RETURN.
```

Here is my attempt:

```
FUNCTION /FOO/GET_REPORT_INFO.
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"*"Lokale Schnittstelle:
*"  IMPORTING
*"     VALUE(IV_REPORT_NAME) TYPE  PROGRAMM
*"  EXPORTING
*"     VALUE(EV_RESULT_JSON) TYPE  STRING
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------


DATA:
ld_return   TYPE BAPIRET2,
it_selscreen_info   TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF BAPI_SELSCREEN_INFO,"TABLES PARAM
wa_selscreen_info   LIKE LINE OF it_selscreen_info,
it_selscreen_texts  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF TEXTPOOL,"TABLES PARAM
wa_selscreen_texts  LIKE LINE OF it_selscreen_texts,
ld_external_user_name TYPE BAPIXMLOGR-EXTUSER.

ld_external_user_name = 'foo'.


CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_XBP_READ_SELSCREEN'
  EXPORTING
    program =                    IV_REPORT_NAME
    external_user_name =        ld_external_user_name
  IMPORTING
    return =                     ld_return
  TABLES
    selscreen_info =             it_selscreen_info
.



ev_result_json = /ui2/cl_json=>serialize( data = it_selscreen_info pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-low_case ).
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  MESSAGE |Error sy-subrc: { sy-subrc }| TYPE 'E'.
ENDIF.


ENDFUNCTION.
```

But the result is always empty.

What am I doing wrong? Is `BAPI_XBP_READ_SELSCREEN` the right method for my goal?

Comment: Can you please have a look at FM RS_SELSCREEN_INFO? It might fullfill your needs, it will give back a list about the parameters and select-options of a report.

Comment: Note that the "interface" of an "executable program" is made of all `PARAMETERS` and `SELECT-OPTIONS` of all of its selection screens, so I guess BAPI_XBP_READ_SELSCREEN is a little bit misnamed or it has an optional parameter for passing the number of a given selection screen. There are also the function modules `RS_REPORTSELECTSCREEN_INFO` and `SELOPTS_AND_PARAMS`, to retrieve all parameters. But I guess only BAPI_XBP_READ_SELSCREEN is an official API ("released" by SAP).

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer about "why `BAPI_XBP_READ_SELSCREEN` doesn't work", not an answer about the main question which is "how to retrieve selection screen parameters".

I'm not sure, but I guess `BAPI_XBP_READ_SELSCREEN` doesn't work because you don't apply the usual logic of XBP.

XBP ("eXternal Background Processing") is a library of APIs used to schedule jobs from an external scheduler. It's based on XMI ("eXternal Management Interface" Framework) which is used by other APIs, and which offers common features, especially the log.

XMI and the applications based on XMI are RFC-capable, so that they can be called remotely.

To use the APIs based on XMI, the minimum is to :

- call the function module `BAPI_XMI_LOGON` to open a session to use a library of APIs you want to use.

  - For XBP, use the parameters INTERFACE = 'XBP' and VERSION = '3.0' (or the version you want).
  - The parameters EXTCOMPANY and EXTPRODUCT can be any max-16-characters names, as agreed with the administrators of the SAP software (they can be possibly blank too), and are subject to `S_XMI_PROD` authorizations if defined. If they are used with different XMI API libraries during the same RFC session, the same values must be passed.
- call the APIs you want (`BAPI_XBP_READ_SELSCREEN` in your case).

  - Note that there's an "external user" parameter (usually `EXTERNAL_USER_NAME`), which is a free field, to be an identifier of the external application. This value is stored with the logs so that you may display or retrieve the XMI logs by external application (transaction `RZ15`).
- call `BAPI_XMI_LOGOFF`

  - There is one `INTERFACE` parameter, whose value must be the same as the one used in `BAPI_XMI_LOGON`.
- In case, you have called an API which updates data, call `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT` to commit these updates.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested BAPI_XBP_READ_SELSCREEN successfully with the program below (please handle the exceptions), so I think it's a good idea to use it :

```
DATA rfcdest TYPE rfcdest.

rfcdest = ''. " XBP is well suited for RFC, but this test doesn't need remote call.

CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_XMI_LOGON'
  DESTINATION rfcdest
  EXPORTING
    extcompany = 'ABAPERS&CO'
    extproduct = 'NICEJOBSCHEDULER'
    interface  = 'XBP'
    version    = '3.0'.

DATA: selscreen_info  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapi_selscreen_info,
      selscreen_texts TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF textpool.

CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_XBP_READ_SELSCREEN'
  DESTINATION rfcdest
  EXPORTING
    program            = 'BTCAUX10'
    external_user_name = 'SRO'
    sel_text_lang      = 'E' " English
  TABLES
    selscreen_info     = selscreen_info
    selscreen_texts    = selscreen_texts.

CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_XMI_LOGOFF'
  DESTINATION rfcdest.

IF rfcdest IS NOT INITIAL. " if you use RFC, close the connection!
  CALL FUNCTION 'RFC_CONNECTION_CLOSE'
    EXPORTING
      destination          = rfcdest
    EXCEPTIONS
      destination_not_open = 1
      OTHERS               = 2.
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check user name "foo". If foo is not external user then result will be empty because of wrong external user.

regards,

Umar Abdullah

Comment: I am very unsure what the external user name means. I tried to use SY-UNAME, but this failed. Do you know why this parameter is needed?

Comment: @guettli I don't know `BAPI_XBP_READ_SELSCREEN` but I know XBP ("eXternal Background Processing"). It's APIs used to schedule jobs from an external scheduler. It's based on XMI ("eXternal Management Interface" Framework) which is used by other APIs, and which offers common features, especially the log. In XMI, the "external user" is a free field, to be an identifier of the external application, this value is stored with the logs so that you may display or retrieve the XMI logs by external application (transaction RZ15). I do a separated answer about how to use XMI.