# Extracting data from SAP spool to Excel using BAPI_XBP_JOB_SPOOLLIST_READ and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ui-automation, sap-gui, saprfc

I'm trying to build interactive Excel templates that extract data from SAP’s spool job using `BAPI_XBP_JOB_SPOOLLIST_READ`. The way I’m approaching the problem is:

1. Run a Transaction Code by means of `RFC_CALL_TRANSACTION_USING` and get SAP to print out the result to spool. The spool job number is returned by the Function Module.
2. Log onto the XBP interface using `BAPI_XMI_LOGON`.
3. Extract the content of the spool job using `BAPI_XBP_GET_SPOOL_AS_DAT` based on the spool job number obtained in Step 1 (originally I was using `BAPI_XBP_JOB_SPOOLLIST_READ`, but change'd it after Sandra's answer)
4. Log off the XBP interface using `BAPI_XMI_LOGOFF`.
5. Delete the spool job using `RSPO_R_RDELETE_SPOOLREQ`.

I’ve succeeded with Step 1 (big shoutout to Sandra Rossi, who provided the crucial piece of the puzzle together with an *amazing* explanation here [Working example for RFC_CALL_TRANSACTION_USING to print to spool using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74681787/working-example-for-rfc-call-transaction-using-to-print-to-spool-using-vba/74761946#74761946) – seriously, you should read it if VBA & SAP integration is of interest to you). I know that this step has worked, becasue I can see the spool job in the `SP01` “List of Spool requests”.

I've also managed Step 2. I can successfully log onto the `XBP` interface with `BAPI_XMI_LOGON`, using the following parameters: (`EXTCOMPANY = "RFC_Excel"`, `EXTPRODUCT = "RFC_Excel"`, `INTERFACE = "XBP"`, `VERSION = "3.0"`), which returns a valid `SESSION_ID`. Steps 4 and 5 are also working fine.

Where I'm having troubles is in Step 3. Originally, in the first draft of this question, I was using `BAPI_XBP_JOB_SPOOLLIST_READ` but changed it now to `BAPI_XBP_GET_SPOOL_AS_DAT` as per Sandra's anwser, yet I still can't get it to work. The call gets executed but the `.Tables("SPOOL_LIST").RowCount` returns an error saying that "Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method" as if the object was not a table and the output of `.Tables("SPOOL_LIST")` is empty, as if the spool request had no content.

I’ve adjusted the code I was using originally to reflect Sandra's suggestions to sue `BAPI_XBP_GET_SPOOL_AS_DAT`:

```vb
Sub SAP_Spool_Job_Read_From_SAP(sSpoolJobNo As String)
    CallResult = False
    
    If sSpoolJobNo = "0" Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim sExternalUserName As String
    Dim ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOn As Object
    Dim ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOff As Object
    Dim ObjR3_RFC_Spool_GetData As Object
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim lSpoolJobNo As Long
    Dim oSpoolOutput As Object
    Dim oSpoolErrors As Object
    
    Dim sXBP_SessionID As String
    Dim sXBP_Message As String
    Dim oXBP_Status As Object
    
    sExternalUserName = "RFC_Excel"
    lSpoolJobNo = sSpoolJobNo * 1
    
    ObjR3_Connection.RFCWithDialog = 1
    
    Set ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOn = ObjR3.Add("BAPI_XMI_LOGON")
    
    'Log onto the XBP interface
    With ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOn
        .Exports("EXTCOMPANY") = sExternalUserName
        .Exports("EXTPRODUCT") = sExternalUserName
        .Exports("INTERFACE") = "XBP"
        .Exports("VERSION") = "3.0"
    End With
    
    CallResult = False
    sXBP_SessionID = "?"
    sXBP_Message = "Pending..."
    CallResult = ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOn.Call
    
    'Check if XBP logon was successful
    If CallResult = True Then
        sXBP_SessionID = ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOn.Imports("SESSIONID").Value
        Debug.Print "ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOn: " & CallResult
        Debug.Print "ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOn: " & ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOn
        Debug.Print "Session ID: " & sXBP_SessionID
        Debug.Print ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOn.Imports("RETURN").Value
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Get Data from Spool content from SAP
    Set ObjR3_RFC_Spool_GetData = ObjR3.Add("BAPI_XBP_GET_SPOOL_AS_DAT")
    Debug.Print lSpoolJobNo
    With ObjR3_RFC_Spool_GetData
        .Exports("SPOOL_REQUEST") = lSpoolJobNo
        .Exports("EXTERNAL_USER_NAME") = sExternalUserName
        .Exports("FIRST_PAGE") = 0
        .Exports("LAST_PAGE") = 0
        Set oSpoolOutput = .Imports("SPOOL_LIST")
         Set oSpoolErrors = .Imports("RETURN")
    End With
    
    CallResult = False

    'Call Request in SAP
    CallResult = ObjR3_RFC_Spool_GetData.Call
    
    If CallResult = True Then
        Debug.Print ObjR3_RFC_Spool_GetData.Exports("SPOOL_REQUEST")
        Debug.Print "ObjR3_RFC_Spool_GetData: " & CallResult
        Debug.Print oSpoolErrors.Value
        Debug.Print "Content: " & vbNewLine & oSpoolOutput
    Else
        GoTo LogOffXMI
    End If
    

LogOffXMI:
    
    Set ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOff = ObjR3.Add("BAPI_XMI_LOGOFF")

    With ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOff
        .Exports("INTERFACE") = "XBP"
    End With
    
    CallResult = ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOff.Call
    
    If CallResult = True Then
        Debug.Print "ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOff: " & CallResult
        Debug.Print ObjR3_RFC_Spool_LogOff.Imports("RETURN").Value
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I should probably add two remarks, in case they’re relevant:

1. The `sUserIdSAP` is the ID of the user who logs onto SAP and who prints the spool request, `sExternalUserName` is the name I came up with for the RFC-enabled templates that I pass as  `EXTCOMPANY` and `EXTPRODUCT` fields. Just in case, I’ve tested both cases in which  `sExternalUserName = "RFC_Excel"` as well as `sExternalUserName = sUserIdSAP`, but this makes no difference.
2. As far as I can tell, the problem is not authorization rights, as I have dealt with all authorization errors (for both `sExternalUserName = "RFC_Excel"` and `sExternalUserName = sUserIdSAP`  scenarios) and SU53 is clear.

I've tried looking through "Connecting External Job Management Systems to the SAP NetWeaver AS ABAP CCMS Job Scheduling System" documentation I've found online, but the truth is I'm out of my depths here. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You pass the value `LIST1S LOCM RFEBKAMONXY1` to the background job name (`JOBNAME`) and the spool request number to the background job number (`JOBCOUNT`), that's wrong. `BAPI_XBP_JOB_SPOOLLIST_READ` can work only if the spool request was generated by a background job, that you can see in `SM37` along with its corresponding spool requests. `SP01` is to see all spool requests, even those generated by foreground processing, Batch Input and so on.

If you only have the spool request number, you must use `BAPI_XBP_GET_SPOOL_AS_DAT` with these parameters:

- `spool_request`

  - Spool request number
- `external_user_name`

  - Any name
- `spool_list`

  - Table with lines of type `STRING` corresponding to the spool data
- `return`

  - Empty if success, or any error like invalid spool request number

NB:

- I see that you call XMI correctly, no programming error, although wrong semantic information concerning company and product. You can see this other [answer which explains more about XMI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53115211/9150270).
- I have edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74761946/9150270) in your other question to indicate `BAPI_XBP_GET_SPOOL_AS_DAT` instead of `BAPI_XBP_JOB_SPOOLLIST_READ`.

Comment: Hi Sandra, thanks for your reply. I've changed the code to use`BAPI_XBP_GET_SPOOL_AS_DAT` instead, but still no luck (I've edditted the question to reflect the changes and where it fails now). The `BAPI_XBP_GET_SPOOL_AS_DAT` has also two parameters you did not mention, `FIRST_PAGE` and `LAST_PAGE`. Are these optional if i want to extract the whole report. If not, or if I need to get the data in chunks, how do I know how many pages the spool request has? Also, I've read through you explanation of the XMI, but still don't understand why the semantic information is wrong.

Comment: Also, is there a way to test BAPI_XBP_GET_SPOOL_AS_DAT in SE37. I've tried, but it tells me I'm not logged onto XMI, even when I use BAPI_XMI_LOGON with SE37 first. It seems as though the logon is terminated once I go back to SE37 to run a new bapi. Is that in any way related to my problem?

Comment: `FIRST_PAGE` and `LAST_PAGE` are optional. I did a test without them, it works well. The parameters are the company and product names, but you pass a user name to both fields. It's technically valid, but semantically it's not.

Comment: It's possible to test a sequence of function modules with `SE37`. In the selection screen of `SE37`, use menu Function Module > Execute > Test Sequence, type `BAPI_XMI_LOGON` and `BAPI_XBP_GET_SPOOL_AS_DAT`, and execute, you'll run in sequence both function modules in the same Internal Session, and after the execution you will have the possibility to save that sequence of function modules and parameter values so that to reuse it.

Comment: I managed to test the sequence in SE37 and ead the spool data as a #-deliniated list with 5 entries, it doesn't work in VBA. The `.Imports("SPOOL_LIST").RowCount` returns an error saying that "Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method". Am I using `.Imports("SPOOL_LIST")` wrong?

Comment: BTW, I tried passing on the spool request number as 0-padded string,  an integer and an integer converted to string (without the leading 0s), in case this makes a difference, but it didn't. I tried reducing the output of the report to a single 4-character column, but still no luck. I also tried passing an incorrect spool request no. (eg. double the current value) and  I get exactly the same behaviour. Maybe I'm passing the number incorrectly? Simply typing it as it appears in SP01 works in SE37, though.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do `SE37` using VBA. VBA doesn't need `SE37`, it calls directly the function modules as a sequence. Shouldn't it be `.Imports("SPOOL_LIST").Rows.Count`? `SPOOL_REQUEST` expects an integer, so padding with zeroes is useless. I don't see `.Call` maybe that's just your issue?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, that's not it. The `.Call` was missing from the code I've pasted sloppily here on StackOverflow, but it was in my actual code. Sorry for that. I've updated the code in the post to reflect the actual code I'm using. The `CallResult = ObjR3_RFC_Spool_GetData.Call` is there, followed by a couple of debugging lines of code to see if any concent is returned. `Debug.Print "Content: " & vbNewLine & oSpoolOutput`  produces the '438' error. The `lSpoolJobNo` 
` .Exports("SPOOL_REQUEST") = lSpoolJobNo` is a numeral as `Long` type.

Comment: My VBA code does not use `SE37`, I'm ust using `SE37` when writing code to understand how a specific transaction works (e.g. what `.Exports` and `.Imprts` it has, etc.).

Comment: I still haven't managed to understand why my code doesn't work, but I did manage to find a workaround. Instead of using `BAPI_XBP_GET_SPOOL_AS_DAT`, I've switched to using `BAPI_XBP_JOB_READ_SINGLE_SPOOL` (with XBP version 2.0 instead of 3.0). The function module differes in that it the `SPOOL_LIST` is a `TABLE` not an `EXPORT`, so I changed my code to .Tables("SPOOL_LIST") and now the `.RowCount` bit returns a value. In fact I ended up using .Tables("SPOOL_LIST_PLAIN") with the `.Exports("RAW") = " "`, because this gives me a cleaner output.